# Generate a random list of custom data type, where values provided to data constructor are somehow bounded within a range

Tags: haskell, random

I have defined a `Point` data type, with a single value constructor like so:

```
data Point = Point {
  x :: Int,
  y :: Int,
  color :: Color
} deriving (Show, Eq)

data Color = None
  | Black
  | Red
  | Green
  | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Bounded)
```

I have found an example of making a `Bounded Enum` an instance of the `Random` class and have made `Color` an instance of it like so:

```
instance Random Color where
  random g = case randomR (1, 4) g of
    (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
  randomR (a, b) g = case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
    (r, g') -> (toEnum r, g')
```

I was then able to find out how to make Point an instance of the Random class also:

```
instance Random Point where
  randomR (Point xl yl cl, Point xr yr cr) g =
    let (x, g1) = randomR (xl, xr) g
        (y, g2) = randomR (yl, yr) g1
        (c, g3) = randomR (cl, cr) g2
    in (Point x y c, g3)
  random g =
    let (x, g1) = random g
        (y, g2) = random g1
        (c, g3) = random g2
    in (Point x y c, g3)
```

So, this let's me make random point values. But, what I'd like to do is be able to create a list of random `Point` values, where the `x` and the `y` properties are bounded within some range whilst leaving the `color` property to be an unbounded random value. Is this possible with the way I am currently modelling the code, or do I need to rethink how I construct `Point` values? For instance, instead of making `Point` an instance of the Random class, should I just create a random list of `Int` in the `IO` monad and then have a pure function that creates n Points, using values from the random list to construct each `Point` value?

Edit, I think I have found out how to do it:

Without changing the above code, in the `IO` monad I can do the following:

```
solved :: IO ()
solved = do
  randGen <- getStdGen

  let x = 2
  let randomPoints = take x $ randomRs (Point 0 0 None, Point 200 200 Blue) randGen

  putStrLn $ "Random points: " ++ show randomPoints
```

This seems to work, `randomRs` appears to let me specify a range...

Presumably because my `Point` data type derives `Eq`?

Or

Is it because my `x` and `y` properties are `Int` (guessing here, but may be "bounded" by default) and I have `Color` derive bounded?

Comment: I'd use the same method, but I'd write `randomRs (Point 0 0 minBound, Point 200 200 maxBound)` so that it's clear the the color is "constrained" between the min and the max color value, so no actual constraint is put on the color. `Color` being bounded matters here, `Int` being bounded does not -- we only need `Random Int` for that since we pass the bounds `0` and `200`.

Comment: Pedantically, we only require the existence of a min / max value for `Color`, not a `Bounded Color` instance. However, under such assumption, it would be silly not to define (or derive) the `Bounded Color` instance. You could then even define `random = randomR (minBound, maxBound)` and avoid replicating your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because of the properties of the Int and Color types, not because of the properties of Point. If one suppresses the `Eq` clause of Point, it still works.

Your code is overall quite good, however I would mention a few minor caveats.

In the Random instance for `Point`, you are chaining the generator states manually; this is a bit error prone, and monadic *do notation* is supposed to make it unnecessary. The Color instance could be simplified.

You are using IO where it is not really required. [IO is just one instance of the MonadRandom class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#t:MonadRandom). If `g` is an instance of `RandomGen`, any `Rand g` is an instance of `MonadRandom`.

The random values you're getting are not reproducible from a program execution to the next one; this is because `getStdGen` implicitly uses the launch time as a random number generation *seed*. It may do that because it is IO-hosted. In many situations, this is a problem, as one might want to vary the choice of random sequence and the system parameters *independently* of each other.

Using monadic style, the basics of your code could be rewritten for example like this:

```
import  System.Random
import  System.Random.TF -- Threefish random number generator
import  Control.Monad.Random

data Point = Point {
  x :: Int,
  y :: Int,
  color :: Color
} deriving (Show, Eq)

data Color = None
  | Black
  | Red
  | Green
  | Blue
  deriving (Show, Eq, Enum, Bounded)

instance Random Color where
  randomR (a, b) g = let (r,g') = randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g
                     in  (toEnum r, g')
  random g = randomR (minBound::Color, maxBound::Color) g


singleRandomPoint ::  -- monadic action for just one random point
  MonadRandom mr => Int -> Int -> Color -> Int -> Int -> Color -> mr Point
singleRandomPoint xmin ymin cmin xmax ymax cmax =
  do
    -- avoid manual chaining of generator states:
    x <- getRandomR (xmin, xmax)
    y <- getRandomR (ymin, ymax)
    c <- getRandomR (cmin, cmax)
    return (Point x y c)
```

And then we can derive an expression returning an unlimited list of random points:

```
-- monadic action for an unlimited list of random points:
seqRandomPoints :: MonadRandom mr =>  
  Int -> Int -> Color -> Int -> Int -> Color -> mr [Point]
seqRandomPoints xmin ymin cmin xmax ymax cmax =
    sequence (repeat (singleRandomPoint xmin ymin cmin xmax ymax cmax))

-- returns an unlimited list of random points:
randomPoints ::  Int  -> Int -> Int -> Color -> Int -> Int -> Color -> [Point]
randomPoints  seed  xmin ymin cmin xmax ymax cmax =
    let
        -- get random number generator:
        -- using Threefish algorithm (TF) for better statistical properties
        randGen = mkTFGen seed
        action  = seqRandomPoints xmin ymin cmin xmax ymax cmax
    in
        evalRand action randGen
```

Finally we can print the first few random points on `stdout`:

```
-- Small printing utility:
printListAsLines :: Show t => [t] -> IO()
printListAsLines xs = mapM_ (putStrLn . show) xs

solved01 :: IO ()
solved01 = do
  let
       seed            = 42  -- for random number generator setup
       -- unlimited list of random points:
       allRandomPoints = randomPoints  seed  0 0 None 200 200 Blue
       count           = 5
       someRandomPoints = take count allRandomPoints
       -- IO not used at all so far

  putStrLn $ "Random points: "
  printListAsLines someRandomPoints

main = solved01
```

### Program execution (reproducible with constant seed):

```
$ randomPoints
Random points: 
Point {x = 187, y = 56, color = Green}
Point {x = 131, y = 28, color = Black}
Point {x = 89, y = 135, color = Blue}
Point {x = 183, y = 190, color = Red}
Point {x = 27, y = 161, color = Green}
$
```

Should you prefer to just get a finite number of points and also get back the updated state of your random number generator, you would have to use [replicate n](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) instead of `repeat`, and [runRand](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) instead of `evalRand`.

Bit more details about the monadic approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890878/11282404).