# How to implement lazy iterate when IO is involved in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, lazy-evaluation

I'm using `IO` to encapsulate randomness. I am trying to write a method which iterates a `next` function `n` times, but the `next` function produces a result wrapped in IO because of the randomness.

Basically, my `next` function has this signature:

```hs
next :: IO Frame -> IO Frame
```

and I want to start with an initial `Frame`, then use the same pattern as `iterate` to get a list `[Frame]` with length `n`. Essentially, I'd like to be able to write the following:

```hs
runSimulation :: {- parameters -} -> IO [Frame]
runSimulation {- parameters -} = do
  {- some setup -}
  sequence . take n . iterate next $ firstFrame
```

Where `firstFrame :: IO Frame` formed by doing something like `let firstFrame = return Frame x y z`.

The problem I am encountering is that when I run this function, it never exits, so it *seems* to be running on an infinite loop (since `iterate` produces an infinite list).

I'm quite new to haskell so not sure where I'm going wrong here, or if my supposition above is correct that it seems that the entire infinite list is being executed.

---

(Update) In case it's helpful, here are the full definitions of `Frame`, `next`, and `runSimulation`:

```hs
-- A simulation Frame encapsulates the state of the simulation at some
-- point in "time". That means it contains a list of Agents in that
-- Frame, and a list of the Interactions that occurred in it as well. It
-- also contains the state of the World, as well as an AgentID counter
-- (so we can easily increment for generating new Agents).
data Frame = Frame AgentID [Agent] [Interaction]
  deriving Show

-- Generate the next Frame from the current one, including scoring the
-- Agents based on the outcomes *in this Frame*.
-- TODO: add in reproduction.
nextFrame :: Reactor -> World -> IO Frame -> IO Frame
nextFrame react w inp = do
  (Frame i agents history) <- inp
  interactions <- interactAll react history agents
  let scoredAgents = scoreAgents (rewards w) interactions agents
  return (Frame i scoredAgents interactions)

-- Run a simulation for a number of iterations
runSimulation :: World -> Reactor -> (Dist, Dist) -> IO [Frame]
runSimulation world react (gen_dist, sel_dist) = do
  startingAgents <- spawnAgents (initial_size world) (agentCreatorFactory gen_dist sel_dist)
  let firstFrame = return (Frame (length startingAgents) startingAgents [])
      next       = nextFrame react world
  sequence . take (iterations world) . iterate next $ firstFrame
```

Comment: You might need to provide more context about `next` and/or `runSimulation`. `sequence . take 1 . iterate id $ return "foo"` returns an action that, when executed, produces `["foo"]`.

Comment: Use `conduit` instead. It has a much more natural interface for dealing with streams that interleave with IO like that.

Comment: Does the function terminate for small values of `n`? You might be getting a combinatorial explosion because the "programs" in the list returned by `iterate` don't really build on the result of the previous one. That is, the `IO` action at position 6 will execute actions 1-5 *again* when executed.

Comment: You might also try `next :: Frame -> IO Frame` and `iterate (>>= next) firstFrame`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how much time computing each `Frame` takes, but I suspect you are doing more work than necessary. The cause is a bit subtle. `iterate` produces a list of repeated applications of a function. For each element in the list, the previous value is reused. Your list is composed of `IO` actions. The `IO` action at position *n* is computed from the already obtained `IO` action at position *n-1* by applying `next`.

Alas, when *executing* those actions, we are not so lucky. Executing the action at position *n* in the list will repeat all the work of the previous actions! We shared work when building the actions themselves (which are values, like almost everything in Haskell) but not when executing them, which is a different thing.

The simplest solution could be to define this auxiliary function with a baked-in limit:

```
iterateM :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> a -> Int -> m [a]
iterateM step = go
    where
    go _ 0 = return []
    go current limit =
        do next <- step current
           (current:) <$> go next (pred limit)
```

While simple, it's a bit inelegant, for two reasons:

- It conflates the iteration process with the limiting of such process. In the pure list world we didn't have to do that, we could create infinite lists and `take` from then. But now in the effectful world that nice compositionality seems to be lost.
- What if we want to do something with each value as it is being produced, without having to wait for all of them? Out function returns everything at the end, in one go.

---

As mentioned in the comments, streaming  libraries like ["conduit"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit), ["streamly"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streamly) or ["streaming"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming) try to solve this problem in a better way, regaining some of the compositionality of pure lists. These libraries have types that represent effectful processes whose results are yielded piecewise.

For example, consider the function [`Streaming.Prelude.iterateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:iterateM) from "streaming", specialized to `IO`:

> iterateM :: (a -> IO a) -> IO a -> Stream (Of a) IO r

It returns a `Stream` that we can "limit" using [`Streaming.Prelude.take`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:take):

> take :: Int -> Stream (Of a) IO r -> Stream (Of a) IO ()

after limiting it we can get back to `IO [a]` with [`Streaming.Prelude.toList_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:toList_) which accumulates all results:

> toList_ :: Stream (Of a) IO r -> IO [a]

But instead of that we could process each element *as it is being produced*, with functions like [`Streaming.Prelude.mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.3.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#v:mapM_):

> mapM_ :: (a -> IO x) -> Stream (Of a) IO r -> IO r

Comment: Ok I think this is correct because when I try to run only 1 or two iterations it returns instantly. I think I sort of understand your implementation of `iterateM`, although it would be great if you could explain the line `(current:) <$> go next (pred limit)`.

Comment: @GTF `(current:)` is an "operator section" http://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator basically a fancy way of writing the function `\xs -> current : xs`. `pred limit` is `limit - 1`. The recursive call `go next (pred limit)` has type `IO [a]` and it's the action that produces "the rest of the elements". `<$>` is an infix version of `fmap`, and it's used to work inside the `IO` action and prepend the current element to the front of the list there.

Comment: Because I don't need to operate on the items as they come out, I have skipped the streaming method for now and your `iterateM` method definitely works (thank you). The thing I don't understand is why one can't write a function which executes the iterative step, stores it as a variable, and adds it both into the list and into the recursion step. That just doesn't seem to work for IO (I get an error about an infinite type).

Comment: @GTF Difficult to say without code. Perhaps merits a question of its own.

Comment: Ok, this has worked for the time being, but I might write up another question separately. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### An elementary solution:

As an alternative to @danidiaz's answer, it is possible to solve the problem without resorting to extra libraries such as `Streaming`, assuming the role of IO can be minimized.

Most of the required code can be written in terms of the [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html) class, of which IO is just one instance. It is not necessary to use IO in order to generate pseudo-random numbers.

The required iteration function can be written like this, in *do notation*:

```
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random.Lazy

iterateM1 :: MonadRandom mr => (a -> mr a) -> a -> mr [a]
iterateM1 fn x0 = 
    do
        y  <- fn x0
        ys <- iterateM1 fn y
        return (x0:ys)
```

Unfortunately, the text of the question does not define exactly what a Frame object is, or what the `next` stepping function does; so I have to somehow fill in the blanks. Also the `next` name gets defined in the libraries involved, so I will have to use `nextFrame` instead of just `next`.

Let's assume that a Frame object is just a point in 3-dimensional space, and that at each random step, one and only one of the 3 dimensions is chosen at random, and the corresponding coordinate is bumped by an amount of either +1 or -1, with equal probabilities.
This gives this code:

```
data Frame = Frame Int Int Int  deriving  Show

nextFrame :: MonadRandom mr => Frame -> mr Frame
nextFrame (Frame x y z) =
    do
        -- 3 dimensions times 2 possible steps: 1 & -1, hence 6 possibilities
        n <- getRandomR (0::Int, 5::Int)
        let fr = case n of
                  0 -> Frame (x-1) y z
                  1 -> Frame (x+1) y z
                  2 -> Frame x (y-1) z
                  3 -> Frame x (y+1) z
                  4 -> Frame x y (z-1)
                  5 -> Frame x y (z+1)
                  _ -> Frame x y z
        return fr
```

At that point, it is not difficult to write code that builds an unlimited list of Frame objects representing the simulation history. Creating that list does not cause the code to loop forever, and the usual `take` function can be used to select the first few elements of such a list.

Putting all the code together:

```
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random.Lazy

iterateM1 :: MonadRandom mr => (a -> mr a) -> a -> mr [a]
iterateM1 fn x0 = 
    do
        y  <- fn x0
        ys <- iterateM1 fn y
        return (x0:ys)

data Frame = Frame Int Int Int  deriving  Show

nextFrame :: MonadRandom mr => Frame -> mr Frame
nextFrame (Frame x y z) =
    do
        -- 3 dimensions times 2 possible steps: 1 & -1, hence 6 possibilities
        n <- getRandomR (0::Int, 5::Int)
        let fr = case n of
                  0 -> Frame (x-1) y z
                  1 -> Frame (x+1) y z
                  2 -> Frame x (y-1) z
                  3 -> Frame x (y+1) z
                  4 -> Frame x y (z-1)
                  5 -> Frame x y (z+1)
                  _ -> Frame x y z
        return fr

runSimulation :: MonadRandom mr => Int -> Int -> Int -> mr [Frame]
runSimulation x y z  =  let  fr0 = Frame x y z  in  iterateM1 nextFrame fr0

main = do
    rng0 <- getStdGen  -- PRNG hosted in IO monad
                       -- Could use mkStdGen or MkTFGen instead
    let
         sim  = runSimulation 0 0 0
         allFrames = evalRand sim rng0   -- unlimited list of frames !
         frameCount = 10
         frames = take frameCount allFrames
    mapM_  (putStrLn  .  show)  frames
```

### Program execution:

```
$ ./frame
Frame 0 0 0
Frame 0 1 0
Frame 0 0 0
Frame 0 (-1) 0
Frame 1 (-1) 0
Frame 1 (-2) 0
Frame 1 (-1) 0
Frame 1 (-1) 1
Frame 1 0 1
Frame 2 0 1
$
```

For large values of `frameCount`, execution time is a quasi-linear function of `frameCount`, as expected.

More on monadic actions for random number generation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836652/how-can-i-generate-different-random-values-in-haskell/57890878#57890878).

Comment: Why can't your `iterateM1` function be written using `IO` instead of `MonadRandom`? Surely the `do` notation and calculating the results in advance like that using `<-` should work?

Comment: I didn't add too much detail about my `next` and `Frame` because I figured it would pollute the question a little, but I'll update the question to add more details.

Comment: @GTF Certainly iterateM1 can be written using IO. But it is the use of IO that prevents your runSimulation function from exiting properly. If you only use a random number generation monad (essentially a state monad) instead of IO, the problem disappears. The IO monad is not *lazy* enough for what you want to do. Note that I have imported Control.Monad.Random.Lazy. Do you need IO for some reason unrelated to random number generation ? You had this sentence "using IO to encapsulate randomness".

Comment: I only need it for randomness, I was just curious as to why IO was different in this way.

Comment: @GTF IO is different because when real world side effects are on, Haskell will not dare to risk reordering these side effects.You have an expression of type IO [Frame], Haskell will insist on doing all the associated side effects being letting you use the result; too bad if there is an infinity of side effects ! You can either add the number of iterations as an extra parameter, as suggested by danidiaz, or move back the "randomness" to the safer realm of non-IO pure computation, as I discussed here for example.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Comment: IO is different because when real world side effects are on, Haskell will not dare to risk reordering these side effects.You have an expression of type IO [Frame], Haskell will insist on doing all the associated side effects being letting you use the result; too bad if there is an infinity of side effects ! You can either add the number of iterations as an extra parameter, as suggested by danidiaz, or move back the "randomness" to the safer realm of non-IO pure computation, as I discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890878/11282404) for example. Sorry URL was eaten away.