# Another question about random numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a version of the [Voltorb game from Pokemon Gold and Silver](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Voltorb_Flip) in Haskell. Now for generation of the board, I want to have a list of (l,r,v) triplets where l is the line, r is the row and v is the value of the field.

Values l and r are implemented with list comprehension since they should be the same every time. As for v though I can't find an option to implement it so that it is 0,1,2 or 3 "randomly" (I know that Haskell is purely functional and there is no true randomness, that's part of the reason why I struggle with this).

If anyone could help with this I'd be very grateful. If you could also maybe give a short explanation as to why that solution works, that would help me a lot.

My current implementation of l and r:

```
field n = [(l,r,v) | l <- [0..n], r <- [0..n]]
```

Comment: Given that there are many questions on random numbers, what has been your trouble adapting the answer?  What has prevented you from generating a list of randoms, `vs`, and define `field n vs = [ ... , v <- vs]`?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I think instead of zipping a list of randoms to grid coordinates, this would generate the cartesian product of the coordinates and the randoms, resulting in `rows * cols * vs` values, instead of the desired `rows * cols` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, there is to be *one* random value per (Int, Int) board position. So the problem cannot be solved by adding a third clause into the comprehension list, such as:

```
field n = [(l,r,v) | l <- [0..n], r <- [0..n], v <- someRandomStuff]
```

as the length of the `field` expression would then be (n+1)x(n+1)x(length of random stuff), and what you want is just (n+1)x(n+1).

A possibility consists in operating in two steps:

1. generating the required (n+1)*(n+1) random values between 0 and 3
2. combining that with the (l,r) values

I assume the reader understands pseudo-random number generation from imperative languages.

Given a seed, you can use a throw-away random number generator returned by function mkStdGen to generate the random values, using function [randomRs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html). Let's use a `ghci` session as a testbed.

Regarding step 1:

```
 λ> import System.Random
 λ> :t randomRs
randomRs :: (Random a, RandomGen g) => (a, a) -> g -> [a]
 λ> 
 λ> seed1=42
 λ> 
 λ> getVSeq n seed = let rng0 = mkStdGen seed  in take  ((n+1)^2) (randomRs (0,3) rng0)
 λ> 
 λ> getVSeq 5 seed1
[1,1,3,0,2,1,0,1,0,1,3,1,2,0,2,3,1,1,3,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,2,1,0,2,0,1]
 λ> 
 λ> length $ getVSeq 5 seed1
36
 λ> field0 n = [(l,r) | l <- [0..n], r <- [0..n]]
 λ> field0 5
[(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(0,5),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),(3,5),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4),(4,5),(5,0),(5,1),(5,2),(5,3),(5,4),(5,5)]
 λ> 

 λ> 
 λ> 
 λ> length  $ field0 5
36
 λ>
```

Now regarding step 2, function  `zip` *almost* solves our problem, except we do not exactly get triplets:

```
 λ> 
 λ> sol0 n seed = zip (field0 n) (getVSeq n seed)
 λ> sol0 5 seed1
[((0,0),1),((0,1),1),((0,2),3),((0,3),0),((0,4),2),((0,5),1),((1,0),0),((1,1),1),((1,2),0),((1,3),1),((1,4),3),((1,5),1),((2,0),2),((2,1),0),((2,2),2),((2,3),3),((2,4),1),((2,5),1),((3,0),3),((3,1),2),((3,2),0),((3,3),2),((3,4),2),((3,5),0),((4,0),2),((4,1),0),((4,2),0),((4,3),0),((4,4),1),((4,5),0),((5,0),2),((5,1),1),((5,2),0),((5,3),2),((5,4),0),((5,5),1)]
 λ>
```

So we need to massage the result of `sol0` a little bit:

```
 λ> 
 λ> sol1 n seed = let flatten = (\((a,b),c) -> (a,b,c))  in  map flatten (sol0 n seed)
 λ> sol1 5 seed1
[(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,2,3),(0,3,0),(0,4,2),(0,5,1),(1,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,2,0),(1,3,1),(1,4,3),(1,5,1),(2,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,1),(2,5,1),(3,0,3),(3,1,2),(3,2,0),(3,3,2),(3,4,2),(3,5,0),(4,0,2),(4,1,0),(4,2,0),(4,3,0),(4,4,1),(4,5,0),(5,0,2),(5,1,1),(5,2,0),(5,3,2),(5,4,0),(5,5,1)]
 λ>
```

So this is what I understood you wanted.
If this is the sole use of random numbers in your application, this could be good enough. Otherwise, I am afraid there is a need to build some knowledge about random number generation in a Haskell functional programming context. You might want to start [here](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/randoms) or [there](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Libraries/Random).

Also, as mentioned by Thomas M. DuBuisson, this has been addressed in several SO questions. You can use the local search engine. Here is [one of the recent ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836652/how-can-i-generate-different-random-values-in-haskell) for example.

### What if you need to get your generator back for reuse ?

In that case, you need to have a function that takes a pre-built generator, and returns BOTH the "field" triplet list and the (final state of the) generator as a (list,finalRng) pair.

You can subcontract the hard (random) work to a function that returns another, simpler pair with just the list of v values and the final state of the generator. That function can be written in recursive fashion, as show below.

```
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random

-- returns the random v values AND the final state of the generator
seqAndGen :: RandomGen tg => (Int,Int) -> Int-> tg -> ([Int], tg)
seqAndGen range count rng0 =
    if (count <= 0)
        then ([],rng0)
        else
            let (v,rng1) = randomR range rng0
                nextSeq  = seqAndGen range (count-1) rng1  -- recursive call
            in
                (v:(fst nextSeq), snd nextSeq)

-- returns the "field" values AND the final state of the generator
fieldAndGen :: RandomGen tg => Int -> tg -> ([(Int,Int,Int)], tg)
fieldAndGen n rng0 =
    let  field0  = [(l,r) | l <- [0..n], r <- [0..n]]
         range   = (0,3)       -- at that level, range gets hardwired
         count   = (n+1)*(n+1) -- number of field/board positions
         pair    = seqAndGen range count rng0  -- the hard work
         vSeq    = fst pair
         endRng  = snd pair
         flatten = \((a,b),c) -> (a,b,c)
         field   = map flatten  (zip field0 vSeq)
    in
         (field, endRng)
```

### Main program:

```
main = do
    let mySeed = 42
        n      = 5
    putStrLn $ "seed=" ++ (show mySeed) ++ "  " ++ "n=" ++ (show n)
    -- get a random number generator:
    let rng0    = mkStdGen mySeed  

    let (field, endRng) = fieldAndGen n rng0
        fieldv = map  (\(a,b,c) -> c)  field
    putStrLn $ "endRng = " ++ (show endRng)
    putStrLn $ "field  = " ++ (show field)
```

### Program output:

```
seed=42  n=5
endRng = 1388741923 1700779863
field  = [(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(0,2,3),(0,3,0),(0,4,2),(0,5,1),(1,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,2,0),(1,3,1),(1,4,3),(1,5,1),(2,0,2),(2,1,0),(2,2,2),(2,3,3),(2,4,1),(2,5,1),(3,0,3),(3,1,2),(3,2,0),(3,3,2),(3,4,2),(3,5,0),(4,0,2),(4,1,0),(4,2,0),(4,3,0),(4,4,1),(4,5,0),(5,0,2),(5,1,1),(5,2,0),(5,3,2),(5,4,0),(5,5,1)]
```

Note that there is a possible variant where instead of passing around the generator, you pass around the infinite list of v values as generated by function [randomRs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#v:randomRs). It is handy to use function [splitAt](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) for such a purpose.
But that assumes you are using randomness just for v values and nothing else, so it is a bit less general and less flexible.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed and has helped me a lot. Would it be possible to get a list with infinite length instead of a set length? Then I could just delete the first entries for every new field so that the player would not have to manually enter a seed with every new game, but rather put in one on start up of the programm.

Comment: @Shini  But actually `randomRs` does return an infinite list. I think in fact it is better to get back also the end state of the generator from the function, so you can reuse it for your next player. I have added code for this at the end of my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short way to separate (1) pseudo-random pure code from (2) random seeding of the pseudo-random generator:

```
--Get the generator in IO monad
main :: IO ()
main = do
  g <- getStdGen
  print $ buildGrid g 5

--Keep as much code as possible pure
buildGrid :: StdGen -> Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
buildGrid g n = zipWith ($) ((,,) <$> [0..n] <*> [0..n])
                            (take ((n+1) * (n+1)) $ randomRs (0,3) g)
```

Or you can keep your original list comprehension, but in that case you have to use a language extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
...
buildGrid g n = zipWith ($) [(y,x,) | y <- [0..n], x <- [0..n]] 
                            (take ((n + 1) * (n + 1)) $ randomRs (0,3) g)
```

Comment: `(,,) <$> [0..n] <*> [0..n] = liftA2 (,,) [0..n] [0..n]` might be clearer. :)