# Pick a random element from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

My code aims to create a word search puzzle. There is a data called Orientation representing the direction of each word in the puzzle.

```
data Orientation =
  Forward | Back | Up | Down | UpForward | UpBack | DownForward | DownBack
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

Now given a input of strings which is `[String]`, I want to randomly assign each string an orientation like `[(Orientation, String)]`

```
assignWordDir :: [String] -> [(Orientation, String)]
assignWordDir [] = []
assignWordDir (s:strs) = (ori, s) : assignWordDir
                        where ori = pickOri [Forward, Back, Up, Down, UpForward, UpBack, DownForward, DownBack]

pickOri :: [a] -> IO a
pickOri xs = do
  i <- randomRIO (0, len)
  pure $ xs !! i
  where len = length xs - 1
```

I cannot compile because the output of `pickOri` is `IO Orientation`, is there any suggestions on how to modify my code? Thanks a lot

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[(IO Orientation, String)]’
                  with actual type ‘[String] -> [(Orientation, String)]’
```

Comment: You can't, unless you change the type to `assignWordDir :: [String] -> IO [(Orientation, String)]`. Would that be acceptable? The main "rule" of IO is that to run IO in a function it has to have type `... -> IO ...`.

Comment: I have tried ```IO [(Orientation, String)]``` and it couldn't compile, when I used ```[(IO orientation, String)]```, it can compile, but when giving it some strings, error occurs, "• No instance for (Show (IO Orientation)) arising from a use of ‘print’ • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it"

Comment: You don't need to involve IO just because you need randomness. IO has a tendency to percolate thru your whole source code once invited in. See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350962/another-question-about-random-numbers-in-haskell/60354483#60354483). Given a list of random integers, you can use `toEnum` to generate random orientations and `zip` to pair random orientations with your String's.

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider modifying the functions so that they stay pure by taking a `RandomGen` parameter. The `pickOri` function, for example, might be modified thusly:

```
pickOri :: RandomGen g => g -> [a] -> (a, g)
pickOri rnd xs =
  let len = length xs - 1
      (i, g) = randomR (0, len) rnd
  in (xs !! i, g)
```

It's necessary to return the new `RandomGen` value `g` together with the selected list element, so that it'll generate another pseudo-random number the next time around.

Likewise, you can modify `assignWordDir` like this:

```
assignWordDir :: RandomGen g => g -> [b] -> [(Orientation, b)]
assignWordDir _ [] = []
assignWordDir rnd (s:strs) = (ori, s) : assignWordDir g strs
  where (ori, g) =
    pickOri rnd [Forward, Back, Up, Down, UpForward, UpBack, DownForward, DownBack]
```

Notice that when recursing into to `assignWordDir`, the recursive function call uses the `g` it receives from `pickOri`.

You can use `mkStdGen` or `newStdGen` to produce `RandomGen` values. Here's an example using `newStdGen`:

```
*Q65132918> rnd <- newStdGen
*Q65132918> assignWordDir rnd ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[(UpBack,"foo"),(Up,"bar"),(UpBack,"baz")]
*Q65132918> assignWordDir rnd ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[(UpBack,"foo"),(Up,"bar"),(UpBack,"baz")]
```

Notice that when you use the *same* `RandomGen` value, you get the same sequence. That's because `assignWordDir` is a pure function, so that's expected.

You can, however, produce a new random sequence by creating or getting a new `StdGen` value:

```
*Q65132918> rnd <- newStdGen
*Q65132918> assignWordDir rnd ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
[(Up,"foo"),(Up,"bar"),(Forward,"baz")]
```

If you want to play with this in a compiled module, you can keep these functions as presented here, and then compose them with a `newStdGen`-generated `StdGen` in the `main` entry point.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really helpful.