# How can I generate a random sequence of elements from a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I've had a look through https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html however I can't see how to use a custom "list" for example an alphanumeric list of  `['a'..'z'] ++ ['0' .. '9']`?

I suppose as a workaround I could instead map a random set of numbers instead.

Comment: You can only sample from some known distribution. For example, would you be able to specify what is the probability distribution for the _length_ of your random list ? If sampling from a fixed list, is it sampling with or without replacement ? You might want to have a look at [previous  question 57836652](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836652/how-can-i-generate-different-random-values-in-haskell), where the length of the “random” list/string was fixed and set in advance.

Comment: You can first set up your candidates list like you mention `['a'..'z'] ++ ['0' .. '9']` and then [shuffle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/232894/105433) the list and `take` as many characters as you like. As a bonus you will get unique random characters at each go.

Comment: That could very likely be disaster and not a "bonus".

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson - Whether getting unique numbers is good or not depends on the context. If at a game of online poker, you find yourself with two kings of Diamond in your virtual hand, you might want to have a serious discussion with the programmer in charge of random number generation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of the work around I mentioned:

```
Prelude> import System.Random
Prelude System.Random> gen <- newStdGen 
Prelude System.Random> x = ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0' .. '9']
Prelude System.Random> fmap (x !! ) (take 10 $ randomRs (0, length x - 1 ) gen)
"h4tm52rfox"
```

Comment: OK thanks, so it looks like sampling with replacement (as you could get the same item twice) from a fixed item list, with a fixed subset size of 10. Quite similar to question 57836652. Is that suitable for your current purposes ?

Comment: Not sure, that that question / answers looked a lot more involved.

Comment: and what is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: No problems that I can see, I just assumed a function like this would already exist.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can do with sampling *with replacement* a fixed number of characters from a fixed string, perhaps it is helpful to repackage a bit the code from [SO_q57836652](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836652/how-can-i-generate-different-random-values-in-haskell).

**Side note**: if you don't want replacement, you will have to look at that [shuffle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/232894/fisher-yates-shuffle-in-haskell) thing pointed to by @Redu in the comments, or maybe also [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.4/docs/System-Random-Shuffle.html).

You can package your specification into a random “*action*”, something that's handy and chainable, like this:

```
import  System.Random
import  Control.Monad.Random
---- import qualified System.Random.Shuffle as SHF -- only for no replacement


-- return many random numbers from some given range:
mkRandSeqMr :: (MonadRandom mr, Random tv) => (tv,tv) -> Int -> mr [tv]
mkRandSeqMr range count =
    let act1 = getRandomR range  in  sequence (replicate count act1)


makeRandomString :: (MonadRandom mr) => String -> Int -> mr String
makeRandomString bigString count = 
    let  range = (0, (length bigString) - 1)
    in   do
             -- "do construct" within the Random monad - not the IO monad
             nums <- mkRandSeqMr range count
             let str = map (bigString !!) nums
             return str
```

The *action* can be used for example like this:

```
main = do
    let
        randomSeed = 4243           -- ideally passed from command line argument
        gen0 = mkStdGen randomSeed  -- for reproducibility of random numbers

        baseString = ['a'..'z'] ++ ['0' .. '9']
        strLen     = 10
        randomStringAction = makeRandomString baseString strLen

        -- need just one random string:
        (randomString1, gen1a) = runRand randomStringAction gen0

        -- harder, need a list of 3 random strings:
        act3 = do
                   -- "do construct" within the Random monad - not the IO monad
                   str1 <- randomStringAction
                   str2 <- randomStringAction
                   str3 <- randomStringAction
                   return [str1, str2, str3]

        (threeRandomStrings, gen1b) = runRand act3 gen0

    putStrLn $ "Single random string: " ++ randomString1
    putStrLn $ "Three random strings: " ++ (show threeRandomStrings)
```

### Program output:

```
Single random string: x7sspkh6ai
Three random strings: ["x7sspkh6ai","cevyxt7mxh","07mryww0fv"]
```

**Side note:** if efficiency is a concern, you might want to use some Data.Map dictionary object to replace the `map (bigString !!)` construct.