# How to use a do block in a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, random, syntax

I want to generate 2 random Int inside a function and use them when calling some other functions. Those other functions expect an Int, so I am trying to get the random values inside a do block. Can someone tell me how I should do this properly?

```
simmulatedGen :: [[Bool]] -> [[Bool]] ->Int -> Double -> Int -> [[Bool]]
simmulatedGen seed minim _ _ 0 = minim
simmulatedGen seed minim dimensiuni t iteratii = do
        {i <- getStdRandom $ randomRIO (0,dimensiuni - 1 :: Int)
        ;j <- getStdRandom $ randomRIO (0,31:: Int)}
    let vecin = selectVecin i j seed
        valoareVecin = deJong dimensiuni (bitGenToDoubleArray dimensiuni vecin)
        valoareMinim = deJong dimensiuni (bitGenToDoubleArray dimensiuni minim)
        percentage = getStdRandom $ randomIO :: Double in  
    if valoareVecin < valoareMinim then simmulatedGen seed vecin dimensiuni t (iteratii - 1) else if t > percentage then simmulatedGen seed vecin dimensiuni t (iteratii - 1) else
                                                            simmulatedGen seed minim dimensiuni t (iteratii - 1)
```

Comment: A `[[Bool]]` return type implies a deterministic return value. If you want the result to be random, you'll need something like `IO [[Bool]]` or some other random-enabling monad. You'll then need to adapt the code so that it works inside that monad.

Comment: Ok, changing the type is easy to do, but how can I get those 2 random Ints inside the function ? At the moment I get an error from it

Comment: The entire function needs to be a `do` block.

Comment: If I do that, i get :parse error on input if"

Comment: Trying to compile your code as it is, we get error messages that are irrelevant to the problem at hand, such as “variable deJong not in scope”. So we would need type signatures and some sort of stub code for the missing functions. Your function code needs to be in a `do` block if it needs to invoke randomness-related functions hosted in the IO monad. You can find some example code here: [SO_q61289405](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289405/how-can-i-generate-a-random-sequence-of-elements-from-a-list-in-haskell).

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand your own logic, but you might try to use something similar to this example:

```
import System.Random

example :: Int -> IO [[Bool]]
example n = do
    x <- randomRIO (1,10)
    if n < x then
       return [[True]]
    else
       return [[False],[False]]


main :: IO ()
main = do
   b1 <- example 5
   b2 <- example 5
   print (b1, b2)
```

Above, we generate a random `Int`, name it `x`, and compare with the input `n`, returning two different lists depending on the comparison. Inside `main`, we call the function twice with the same arguments, but we can observe different results because of the randomness.

As a thumb rule, use `x <- f args` when `f` returns `IO something` (the result can be random) and `let x = f args` when the result is not inside `IO` (the result is deterministic). This is not a hard rule, but in most cases you will want to use this.